# How to hook jinja %include% and %extend% handlers?

Tags: include, jinja2, handler, extend

Before jinja handles my templates I want to make some preparations.
It would be good override some method like:

```py
def OnBeforeInclude(filename: str, context: str, render_args: dict) -> str:
    return context.upper()
```